# running a script in a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Just new to Docker so please bear with me. I'm trying to use docker-compose with an Alpine Dockerfile. Ideally I'd spin the alpine image up and have it continue to run

```
FROM alpine:edge
```

I have a shell script in my mounted volume in my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
 solr-service: 
  build: ./solr-service
  volumes:
    - /Users/asdf/customsolr/trunk:/asdf/customsolr/trunk 
  ports:
    - 8801:8801
```

Referenced within the mounted volume at /Users/asdf/customsolr/trunk/startsolr.sh I have a script which I've tried all kinds of approaches to run and stay running. Basically if I run this locally on my own machine outside of Docker it spins up the files in its dir in a mini custom jetty instance. When I try to invoke the script thru RUN or CMD the docker container has already finished or it cannot not find the needed startup.jar.

```
#!/bin/sh

export DEBUG_ARGS=''
export DEBUG_ARGS='-Xdebug -
Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8909'

java -Xms512M -Xmx1024M $DEBUG_ARGS -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -server -Dsolr.solr.home=cores -Dsolr.useFilterForSort=false -Djetty.home=_container -Djetty.logs=_container/logs -jar _container/start.jar
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: What is the `entrypoint` or `cmd` for the image you are building?

Comment: Post your dockerfile and the logs also when you run the container

Answer (score 0):

Alpine image doesn't come with java installed, so unless you're adding it to your image inside Dockerfile, I'd say that the script just finishes and your container exists immediately.

It would be helpful if you provide your Dockerfile, full docker-compose.yml and log from container.